# In-App Purchase not displaying on App Store

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have recently develop one app with In-App purchase.

App is also approved by apple.

But the issue is:

My app is displaying on App Store. But there is no "In-App" displaying in app store.

So user doesn't know that, my app has In-App purchase for full version.

I have tested app with In-App.

Is there like that, after some time of app approval, In-App will be displayed on App Store. Because my app is just approved.

Please help me if there is any other setting or I miss any other thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an app with in-app purchase as well. I'm pretty sure the "Top In-App Purchases" started showing up the day after someone actually purchased it.

Regardless, if you want users to know you have an in-app purchase, you should use your description and screenshots to get that across.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. So you mean that, there is no any issue with In-App. When someone will purchase the full version of app through In-App, then "Top In-App Purchase" section will be display in my app on App Store. right?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Have you had any purchases, or purchased it yourself?